# What is the difference between COM objects and NuGet packages?

Tags: .net, windows, com, nuget

In some study project I have the task to add a reference to system com object, and I know it is a dynamic library, but I absolutely don't understand what the difference between COM objects and NuGet packages are. I also don't understand when we need use COM objects, and when NuGet packages.

What is the difference between COM objects and NuGet packages? When should we use which?

Comment: Not sure, what you are expecting ... _"COM is a platform-independent, distributed, object-oriented system for creating binary software components that can interact. COM is the foundation technology for Microsoft's OLE (compound documents) and ActiveX (Internet-enabled components) technologies."_ says [Component Object Model (COM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal), while nugets are basically glorified managed dlls with some tooling attached.

Comment: COM is a special binary format/interface to get to functionality. Nuget is a package format to get things deployed. You could have a COM object distributed in a nuget package. They do not have many things in common or are used for comparable things.

Comment: ^^ Meaning: Usually, you won't have the question "COM _or_ Nuget". Nowadays it would be quite unusual to have references to 3rd party libs that do _not_ come in form of a nuget.

Comment: You rarely have a choice.  A vendor may well favor a COM library for their product because they created it a long time ago or want to support platforms other than .NET.  If you do have the choice then favor Nuget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COM is a decades-old component technology, originally (IIRC) created by Microsoft. It predates .NET and was originally intended to enable programmers to reuse libraries or extend existing applications. COM components were typically dll files, and were often written in C++ or Visual Basic.

The protocol was binary, and you had to 'register' the component (in the Windows registry, IIRC). Registration was machine-wide and done by identifier, which meant that you could only have one version of a COM component installed on a machine.

From a .NET developer's perspective, I'd consider it a legacy technology.

NuGet, on the other hand, is a package management system. In .NET, you can create reusable libraries (also dll files). While it's possible to register a .NET library as a COM component (by implementing some special interfaces or something - I honestly no longer remember how one worked with it), you can also just copy the dll file to the folder where your .NET application runs, and it becomes available to that process.

This means that you can have many versions of the same .NET library on the same machine. Application A uses version 1.1 of a library, while application B uses version 3.2.

In the first years of .NET, you'd typically download reusable libraries as Zip files, unpack them, and copy them around as necessary.

This did solve the 'dll hell' problem of COM, but was tedious and somewhat error-prone for other reasons. Thus, like in other languages, a package manager system emerged. This is called NuGet, and is similar to package managers for other languages/platforms.

NuGet is a way to distribute and manage reusable libraries, most of which are .NET dlls.

Comment: Registration-free COM was introduced in XP and allowed COM components to be registered via local file-based manifest rather than using the Registry, so that bit of the answer is itself a bit outdated.

Answer (score 1):

COM - Component Object Model, COM is a binary interface introduced by Microsoft.

- COM objects are compiled code libraries (.dll files) that expose interfaces through which other applications can connect with them.
- COM objects are used for integrating with legacy systems or old technology components developed in languages like C++. They are also used in Microsoft Office applications or other Windows-specific ways.

NuGet is a package manager for .NET development and NuGet packages are managed by Visual Studio.

- NuGet packages are collections of compiled code and metadata in a single file.
- The NuGet Package Manager can be used for installing, upgrading and removing of packages automatically.
- You can get third-party community help when using NuGet packages while developing an application.
- NuGet packages are used for modern .NET development workflows.
- NuGet packages allow sharing of applications with others.